# Add new Data source in Visual Studio 2019 Faild

Tags: c#, winforms, datasource

I am using VS 2019 and want to add a new data source to my project. My project is simple and just want to add new data source but getting following error.

"this window is not supported for the selected project. For steps o enable data binding, please visit

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/windows-forms-data-binding?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

"
I don't know what to do with it. Am i missing something? Plz help me to sort this out.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: I think don't need to share the code. It's not related to code. I can't just add new Data source from Project-> Add new data source. Getting the error mentioned above.

Comment: private void addbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDB"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.Connection = con;
            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TestTable Values('"+textBox1.Text+"')";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            count++;
            getIndex--;
        }

Answer (score 8):

Do you use the ".Net Core" project? It seems that the data binding option only works to ".NET Framework" Windows Forms projects, not to .NET Core Windows Forms projects.